# Android - How to start select mode

Tags: android, action-menu

In my Android app I need to provide some custom actions on the contextual action menu after the user selects some text. To do so, I capture long clicks and start the action mode, providing a custom `ActionMode.Callback` (as pointed out in [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB)). The problem is that this way the selection text cursors won't show up. So, is there any way to activate the selection text mode programmatically??

Answer (score 0):

```
public void SelectText(){
  try{
    KeyEvent shiftPressEvent = 
       new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 
       KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT, 0, 0);
   shiftPressEvent.dispatch(mWebView);
  }catch(Exception e){
   throw new AssertionError(e);
  }
 }
```

In this case we are activating text select on mWebView

Comment: Nothing happening. Already checked that this code is being executed, but the cursors don't show up (testing in ICS)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`startActionMode()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActionMode%28android.view.ActionMode.Callback%29).

See [How to invoke the ActionBar's ContextMenu-like behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6162684/2603965)